# How to combine/merge the different two data as one series in echarts angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

How to merge the two data as one series in eharts?

here's the code:

```
option = {
    title: {
        text: '堆叠区域图'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross',
            label: {
                backgroundColor: '#6a7985'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['Data1']
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'category',
            boundaryGap: false,
            data: ['周一', '周二', '周三', '周四', '周五', '周六', '周日']
        }
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value'
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Data1',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
            name: 'Data2',
            type: 'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
        }
    ]
};
```

what I'm trying to do is to merge/combine the two different data in one series and when they are already combine how to define if its data1 or data2?

sample output:
[image]

Comment: So... do you want merge two series? right?

Comment: I think you should merge data before render the chart